# HTML : hover effect for all cell with different colours

Tags: html, css, hover

Is it possible to have same hover effect for all table cells that have different colour?

```
td:hover {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

<td style="background-color:yellow;">
<td style="background-color:red;">
```

the hover effect doesn't work.

then I tried to use #id to assign different cell colour for each cell, still hover effect not working.

> From w3schools : hover MUST come after :link and :visited (if they are
>   present) in the CSS definition, in order to be effective!

I've already put the hover after the link.

Is there anything I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override using `!important` - since you used inline `style=""`

```
background-color: black !important;
```

or **rather** use classes:

```css
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="yellow">YELLOW</td>
    <td class="red">RED</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

since inline styles are sign of poor design anyways.

Comment: Hi Roko, thank you for the code, I am now able to assign colour to the cells using class! But not for the first table cell, that cell only taking the background colour of the page. Do you need to see my code to know what caused the problem?

Comment: @Santa no, I presume, you should inspect element and see what *rule* is overwriting your *try*. When you identify that rule you need to add than higher specificity to the overriding new rule like i.e: `#parent table td:hover` etc... Try to figure it out alone :) do an investigation of your own code using Developer Tools. If it still does not works create a jsBin or jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> An important difference between the `style tag` and the `inline attribute` is **specificity**. Specificity determines when one style overrides another. Generally, inline styles have a higher specificity.
>
> REF: https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

#### Inline style have higher `Specificity` than CSS style sheet, so you must use !important to overwrite it.

OR

#### AS in @Roko C. Buljan answer, use class instead of inline style could avoid this kind of problem, and it is recommended to do that way.

```css
td:hover {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td style="background-color:yellow;">111</td>
  <td style="background-color:red;">222</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of in-lining the style for the table try using classes instead.